# Html5 and Javascript QR Scanner with JsQRScanner

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using JsQRScanner on a webpage to scan qr code

[here is the code](https://github.com/jbialobr/JsQRScanner)

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
function onQRCodeScanned(scannedText)
{
    var scannedTextMemo = document.getElementById("scannedTextMemo");
    if(scannedTextMemo)
    {
        scannedTextMemo.value = scannedText;
    }
}

//this function will be called when JsQRScanner is ready to use
function JsQRScannerReady()
{
    //create a new scanner passing to it a callback function that will be invoked when
    //the scanner succesfully scan a QR code
    var jbScanner = new JsQRScanner(onQRCodeScanned);
    //reduce the size of analyzed images to increase performance on mobile devices
    jbScanner.setSnapImageMaxSize(300);
    var scannerParentElement = document.getElementById("scanner");
    if(scannerParentElement)
    {
        //append the jbScanner to an existing DOM element
        jbScanner.appendTo(scannerParentElement);
    }        
}
```

the result in the "Scanned text" textarea.

I want open the result url immediately in the same page instead of showing it in the scanned text
Thank you

Comment: Instead of append the 'scannerParentElement' used the Window.location.href= scannerParentElement; or Window.open (scannerParentElement);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `window.open();` javascript to open scanned URL. Suppose if your scanned URL is **scannedText** then you can use it like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function onQRCodeScanned(scannedText)
{
    var scannedTextMemo = document.getElementById("scannedTextMemo");
    if(scannedTextMemo)
    {
        scannedTextMemo.value = scannedText;
        window.open(scannedText); //open scanned webpage
    }
}

//this function will be called when JsQRScanner is ready to use
function JsQRScannerReady()
{
    //create a new scanner passing to it a callback function that will be invoked when
    //the scanner succesfully scan a QR code
    var jbScanner = new JsQRScanner(onQRCodeScanned);
    //reduce the size of analyzed images to increase performance on mobile devices
    jbScanner.setSnapImageMaxSize(300);
    var scannerParentElement = document.getElementById("scanner");
    if(scannerParentElement)
    {
        //append the jbScanner to an existing DOM element
        jbScanner.appendTo(scannerParentElement);
    }        
}
</script>
```

Comment: It works fine
But it keep loading the url till I move the camera away from the QR
I want to close the <div> camera the url begin loading